# Good assumption: Programmers nowadays search & replace globally when refactoring?

Tags: replace, refactoring

Nowadays with the use of modern code editors, it's pretty simple to do a search & replace globally (whole project). I use this for refactoring or renaming things on a global scale.

Now I want to verify if it can be assumed that most people use the global search & replace technique for refactoring or renaming things.

Comment: I'd rather think that many people will use the built-in refactoring and renaming tools of their IDEs, which are a whole lot more sophisticated than just find&replace...

Comment: I must not be "most people".  I write programs that have lots of scopes/namespaces.  What I want to do is rename an identifier within its scope.  Global replace is pretty terrible at that in general. That's why you need your IDE to help you get it right.